# select box with 1px separator line (option) in safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I'm trying to add a 1px separator line (option) to a select box, see demo below.

This works great in chromw windows/mac but does not work in safari - I get a thick normal height option.

As you can see I tried quite a few styles but no luck on safari.

How can I get the same effect in safari ?

```html
<select size=6>
  <option>First Option</option>
  <option>Second</option>
  <option style="line-height: 1px !important;height:1px  !important; min-height:1px  !important; max-height:1px  !important; padding:0  !important; font-size: 1pt  !important; background-color: #000000;" disabled>&nbsp;</option>
  <option>Third</option>
  <option>Fourth</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying to semantically group options together, instead of styles, consider using the [`<optgroup>` html tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup) which was designed for this purpose. Example:

```html
<select>
  <optgroup label="Group A">
    <option>First Option</option>
    <option>Second</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Group B">
    <option>Third</option>
    <option>Fourth</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: What is your goal? Why do you want a separator line between the first set of options and the second set of options?